# Algumas teclas não estão funcionando no meu VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, teclado, configuração

As teclas <kbd>F1</kbd> à <kbd>F12</kbd>, não estão funcionando. Uso um notebook DELL, com windows 10. Coloquei o cursor em cima de uma classe, dei <kbd>F12</kbd> para ir até a função e nada. Dei um <kbd>F5</kbd> e o projeto não rodou. O que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: A tecla FN do teclado está pressionada? Verifique, pois caso esteja, poderá ser esse o problema.

Comment: Se você for usar frequentemente as teclas de função é possível alterar na inicialização do notebook o comportamento padrão delas de modo a você não precisar pressionar também a tecla <kbd>Fn</kbd> nesses casos, mas passar a precisar da tecla <kbd>Fn</kbd> quando usá-las pra controlar volume, brilho, ligar ou desligar wifi, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Comportamento esquisito, mas você pode tentar resetar seu Visual Studio para as configurações iniciais. Mas antes de fazer isso tente fazer aqueles testes básicos, reinicie o Visual Studio e/ou reinicie seu Windows.

O Visual Studio oferece alguns parâmetros de linha de comando que podem ser utilizados para realizar um reset em vários tipos de configurações do IDE, segue abaixo uma lista com uma pequena explicação sobre cada uma:

Para executa-los basta abrir o Executar com <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> e digitar o comando de abertura do IDE junto com o argumento (pode ser feito de outras maneiras, mas é só um exemplo), da seguinte forma `devenv.exe [/parâmetro]`.

- `/ResetUserData` - Reseta todas as configurações de usuário;
- `/ResetSettings` - Restaura o IDE para as configurações padrões e opcionalmente permite que você um arquivo de configurações específico através de mais um argumento;
- `/ResetSkipPkgs` - Remove todas as tags de SkipLoading adicionadas a pacotes do Visual Studio.
- `/ResetAddin` - Remove comandos associados a um Add-in específico.

Você pode verificar a descrição original desses parâmetros utilizando `devenv.exe /?`.

Tente realizar esses procedimentos, se não funcionar talvez a única solução seja reinstalar seu Visual Studio